# How to setup a DX Project Workflow to customize Production

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, developer

I am trying to understand the workflow of creating a DX project from an existing Production Org so that I can port over all metadata to a DevHub and ScratchOrg in order to make customization.

I am using Trailhead orgs and perform the following steps to the best of my understanding but must be missing something since I get an error when deploying to my ScratchOrg.

1. Create a Trialhead Org for Production, MyProductionOrg, and add a custom object, MyCustomObject
2. Create a Trailhead Org for Development, MyDevHub, and enable Dev Hub and Source Tracking
3. Create a DX project in VSCODE
4. Authorise MyProductionOrg

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias MyProductionOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
```

5. Authorise MyDevHub

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias MyDevHub --setdefaultdevhubusername
```

6. Create a Scratch Org, MyScratchOrg

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config\project-scratch-def.json --setalias MyScratchOrg --durationdays 7 --setdefaultusername --json --loglevel fatal
```

7. Generate a Manifest of MyProductionOrg

```
sfdx force source manifest create --fromorg MyProductionOrg --manifestname=allMetadata --outputdir manifest
```

- Inspect allMetadata.xml contains MyCustomObject__c

8. Retrieve Object from Manifest

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -x manifest/allMetadata .xml
```

9. Deploy Metadata to ScratchOrg

```
VSCODE: SFDX: Deploy Source In Manifest To Org
```

**EXPECTED** MyCustomObject__c appears in Object Manager of MyScratchOrg

**ACTUAL :** A Slew of object errors including

```
- In field: xxx - no xxx named xxx found 
- Cannot update SLA process that is in use
- Required field is missing: xxx
- xxx content type cannot be updated
- Value too long for field: xxx maximum length is: xxx
- Custom Object Definition ID: bad value for restricted picklist field: xxx
- You can't edit tab settings for xxx
- The default certificate cannot be selected as the Request Signing Certificate 
- You can't customize this model until you enable Einstein Attribution.  
- To access CustomerDataPlatformSettings through the API, please enable Data Cloud.  
- There was an error enabling or disabling a setting 
- You do not have the level of access required to deploy this component
```

Comment: Are those errors coming from the object metadata or from something else? Like profiles / permissionsets / security settings etc?

Comment: I am not sure, but I only create a single custom object to try to get to grips with the workflow process and would expect things to work seamlessly for such a bare bones migration to a Scratch Org

Comment: It's worth noting that a number of these errors are related to enabling features that are enabled in your Production org. The easiest way to solve a number of those issues is to look at creating an Org Shape to ensure that your scratch org definition matches production. Details to do that are [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_intro.htm)

Comment: You have a list of commands and instructions here that you can use to init a DX project from a production org :) https://sfdx-hardis.cloudity.com/salesforce-ci-cd-setup-existing-org/